# Is there a database of pollen-seed distances across plant species?

Tags: botany, reproduction, literature, database

I was enjoying Richard Smith's excellent answer to [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/are-there-any-motile-plants?rq=1), and wondered:

If you consider the pollen/seed distribution range to be plant locomotion, is there a database that compares these distances across plant taxa, or perhaps a paper that treats these distances as a trait (in a phylogenetic context, for example)? One might assume that in the transition from wind-pollination to animal pollination (or from wind seed dispersal to animal seed dispersal) there is a sacrifice of decreased distance for increased "accuracy", but maybe this isn't the case.

It seems like this information should be around somewhere – it has relevance to evolution, speciation, climate change adaptation, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In my searching I didn't find a comprehensive database of this information. There are biologists interested in analyzing seed dispersal distance as a trait however.

[Vittoz and Enger (2007)](https://serval.unil.ch/notice?pid=serval:BIB_ABDB608A7111) used plants with known seed dispersal along with characteristics about these species to predict dispersal distances for other species.

There is another study [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2745.2011.01867.x/abstract) that examines the relationship of plant height and seed dispersal. They provide interesting background information as well on the trade-offs associated with a particular dispersal mode. For example,

"It is often assumed that there is a trade-off between maternal provisioning and dispersal capacity, leading small-seeded species to disperse further than large-seeded species."

It is certainly an area of research actively being pursued but there doesn't seem to be a list or database of these dispersal traits by species. There is information on dispersal distance by mode in the appendix of the second link I've provided.